# Cell value chosen based on another cell (date)

Tags: excel-formula

We have three classification of employees, classification is based on date of hire. Column A
In column C I have the employee date of hire.

I want Column A to automatically change to CI, CII, or CIII based on their tenure.

CI=under 2 years
CII=2-4 years
CII 4 years or more

I played with a few forumlas but could not do it simply (at least not in my mind).

Comment: Please share the few formulas that you wrote already - that it is about here - and what were there results for which entry values? Best check ["How to write good"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Without any formula - some might think that you just delegate the work to some other programmers and did not at all write any formula.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.